# How to access resouces from sub module to main spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-module

I injected the submodule in `build.gradle` file with `implementation(project(":modules:modules1"))` but still resources of my `modules1` are not accessible in main project on runtime.

```
- main-application
  - modules
    - module1
      - src
        - main
        - java
        - resources
  - src
    - main
      - java
      - resources
```